# emulate Excel's COUNTIF in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

One way COUNTIF is used in Excel is to count all the matches in a column based on a **changing** base column.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 'a'],
    ['b', ''],
    ['c', ''],
    ['d', ''],
    ['e', 'b'],
    ['f', ''],
    ['g', ''],
    ['h', 'c'],
    ['i', ''],
    ['j', ''],
    ['k', 'd'],
    ['a', ''],
    ['b', 'b']],
    columns=['X', 'Y']
)
```

Desired result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 'a', 2],
    ['b', '', 0],
    ['c', '', 0],
    ['d', '', 0],
    ['e', 'b', 2],
    ['f', '', 0],
    ['g', '', 0],
    ['h', 'c', 1],
    ['i', '', 0],
    ['j', '', 0],
    ['k', 'd', 1],
    ['a', '', 0],
    ['b', 'b', 2]],
    columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z']
)
```

Here, COUNTIF would be counting the number of a's in the first column, then the number of blanks in the first column, then the number of blanks in the first column, ..., then the number of b's in the first column, etc.

Is there a way to construct that third column in pandas in a vectorized way without iterating through the second column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and fill the missing values with zeros.

```
df['Z'] = df['Y'].map(df['X'].value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: apologies and thank you so much for your time in editing and answering the bad question.